# Problem with conditionally hiding rows of a grid in generated PDF reports

Tags: eclipse, birt

I am generating PDF/HTML report from a BIRT template.

I am using "visibility" property to hide a grid row conditionally. It is working fine and that row is hidden in generated report.

But, I am getting a bottom border missing from the upper grid row in my PDF report and although HTML report is generated perfectly fine.

To understand it see below, for example my report looks like following when visibility is 'true' for row containing location element.

---

Name

---

Description

---

Location

---

verdict

---

and after visibility is 'false' for 'Location' row, it is showing as following in generated report.

---

Name

---

Description
verdict

---

The grid line between Description and verdict is missing.

I am using BIRT 2.1.2. Is this a known problem in this version?

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you implementing the separator line?  Are you just creating a border around the grid cell?  That entire cell/row is getting suppressed along with the border.

To get the effect you want, try applying your visibility rule to the data (text) item itself rather than the Grid element.  You could also add a horzzontal rule to the end of each of the text elements to insert a divider that would not be affected by the grid's visibiltiy.

Comment: The border for the grid cell is of width 1, and "thin" type. do you suggest anything else?

If i apply visibility rule to only data item then it will show an empty gird, for the row where visibility results in "False".

If I deliberately add a horizontal rule below text item, then it will (possibly) results in a very thick separator line, whenever visibility is true for that row, because of grid border and horizontal rule both.

Comment: If you add a Horizontal rule with a size attribute of 1, that will be a 1-pixel thick line (<HR SIZE="1">) Then you would siply remove the borders fromt the grid entirely.